# While Loop Python -

Tags: python

I would need to do a loop on the excel snapshot below. So I need to count if the Return time is greater than the Order time in the next cell (compare cell 1 in Return value with cell 2 in Order Time, and so on). When it finds that cell meets the condition, count 1 and move on to the next cell in order to do the same.

[image: Excel file snapshot]

Please see below the code I used (didn't help much), so it would be amazing if anyone could help:

```
i=0

while i == 0:
  
 if df['Return time'].all() > df['Order time'].all():
  i +=1
```

Comment: When you add 1, the `while` condition is no longer true, so the loop stops.

Comment: Why do you have a loop? The `if` condition doesn't change each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use for loop, need change while condition, because `while i == 0:` only run once.

```py
count = 0
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    if x["Return time"] > x["Order time"]:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

More pandas way is

```py
# filter df
df = df[df["Return time"] > df["Order time"]]
# count number
df.count()["Return time"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much!!!

Ildefonso C.

Answer (score 0):

Update the while loop condition because in this case, it will run only once.

for ref: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-do-you-execute-a-while-loop-in-python